# Getting images from blog feed in HTML page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, rss

Can anyone suggest a simple procedure to get images from an RSS feed in an HTML page using jQuery?

I have tried the following code which returns images on Internet Explorer and Dreamweaver live view but not on Firefox. The code successfully gets images from XML files anyways.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://wmtechnology.wordpress.com/feed?alt=rss",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
});
});




   function xmlParser(xml) {



   $(xml).find("image").each(function () {

   $("#a1").append('<img src="'+$(this).find("url").text()+'">' + $(this).find("title").text());


    });



    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <p id="a1"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: isnt this a cross domain call?

Comment: the url given in the code is a rss feed... Can you pont out anny errors in the code?

Comment: when i user a static xml file instead of the url... the code seems to work properly

Comment: Im getting a transport error here..thats why im asking you if this is a cross domain call. if it is, ajax will not allow it.

Comment: make an ajax call to a method in the server which will consume this url and return xml

Comment: ok.. goin to try that out

Comment: try adding an error callback to your `ajax` : `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status);alert(thrownError)}`

Comment: Try using firebug and see if any error returning when making a call to that page.

Comment: there is no error in that code... running successfully on IE but not on FF and chrome. Can you tell me the solution

Comment: @hungerpain depending on browser(as @ aks has mentioned above), the request will or wont go through varying on browser. You are relying on Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which can't, as far as I am aware, be activated by an HTML tag.

Comment: @ir-g ... could not succeed in doing it through xml parsing, however got the solution by using jgfeed which used json.... it works fine now in every browser... :)

Comment: @aks does this question need to remain then? You may wish to add in your solution below, so other people can use this question for reference.

Comment: IE detects active x control, which chrome does not have by default I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't work is because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for JavaScript. You're only allowed to make requests to the same host from which you served the page.

You have to send a request to your own server and let the server retrieve the XML for you and return that (like a proxy). That'll work on all browsers.